# Bar graph in python for 3 datasets

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I have 3 datasets. I want to plot their graph.

```py
width=0.25
d1=[9.31,8.0,9.9,9.1]
plt.xticks(x,['3','5','9','11'])
plt.bar(x,d1,-width,align='edge')



d2=[10.31,11.0,12.9,19.1]
plt.xticks(x,['3','5','9','11'])
plt.bar(x,d2,+width,align='edge')

d3=[8.31,10.0,11.9,13.1]
plt.xticks(x,['3','5','9','11'])
plt.bar(x,d3,width,align='edge')
```

and I have 3 legends `d1`, `d2`, `d3`. How can I plot it equal...

I am not getting accurate bar graph.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just understand what you mean. You want to draw three different graphs on the same x point.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width=0.25
x = [1,2,3,4]
d1=[9.31,8.0,9.9,9.1]
d2=[10.31,11.0,12.9,19.1]
d3=[8.31,10.0,11.9,13.1]

def plot3graphs(x, d1, d2, d3, width):

    plt.xticks(x,['3','5','9','11'])

    x1 = [e-1.5*width for e in x]
    plt.bar(x1,d1,width,align='edge')

    x2 = [e-0.5*width for e in x]
    plt.bar(x2,d2,width,align='edge')

    x3 = [e+0.5* width for e in x]
    plt.bar(x3,d3,width,align='edge')


plot3graphs(x, d1, d2, d3, width)
plt.show()
```